# Is there a separate term for confectionery art?

Tags: expressions, terminology, word-usage

I know that there's a term for somebody who makes confectionery (*confectioner*) but is there a separate term for *confectionery art*? Whenever I see elaborately made cakes looking like statues and paintings, for instance, I've always been curious of whether there's an established discipline for that beyond just being 'confectionery'. I've tried preliminary searches both on this site and elsewhere online but to no avail.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Note that cakes are patisserie, not confectionary. Confectionery is things like sweets/candies and chocolates.

Answer (score 8):

The term you may be after is ***sugarcraft***

> The art of creating confectionery or cake decorations from sugar paste. [[ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sugarcraft)]

There's a [British Sugarcraft Guild](http://bsguk.org/who-we-are/), who have images such as these to illustrate particular examples of their members' confectionery art:

[image: Sugarcraft iced cake] [image: Sugar decorations]

(Both images from British Sugarcraft Guild)

The term [appears to be well-established](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=sugarcraft&ie=UTF-8), although it may be mainly British.

Comment: *Sugar work* is also used, and I recall hearing it in the *Victoria* miniseries. In the series, Mr Fancatelli is based on a real person. https://archive.org/details/royalenglishand01frangoog

Answer (score 4):

As far as **job titles** go:

Cake Artist or Cake Designer are both good options.

> I usually say "cake artist" but now that I think about it, how about "pastry artist?"
>
> I call myself designer/baker.
>
> I am a Professional Baker and Cake Designer

Taken from [this discussion](http://www.cakecentral.com/forum/t/738797/silly-question-what-do-you-call-yourself) among cake 'designers', there are a few other ideas there too.

As per Lawrence's comments, if you were looking for phrases to describe "**the discipline**" versus the job title, then you could modify the titles like so:-

> Cake Artist --> Cake Artistry
>   Cake Designer --> Cake Design

Comment: @Lawrence Good points i'll amend my answer in light of your comment

Answer (score 1):

The term *cake decorating* covers the mid-to-elaborate range of *cake* art, a subset of *confectionery* art.

> Cake decorating is one of the sugar arts that uses icing or frosting and other edible decorative elements to make plain cakes more visually interesting. Alternatively, cakes can be molded and sculpted to resemble three-dimensional persons, places and things.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cake_decorating#See_also)

*Food presentation* spans a broad range that covers a superset of *confectionery art*.

> Food presentation is the art of modifying, processing, arranging, or decorating food to enhance its aesthetic appeal.
>   [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_presentation)

For the term itself, your own *confectionery art* works. Have a look at the links for a [pinterest page](https://au.pinterest.com/whitcivi/confectionery-art/) that includes elaborate sculptures and a competition that includes the words "confectionery art", called the [International Confectionery Art Competition](http://www.europain.com/events/international-confectionery-art-competition).